# Check which base classes are implemented

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have two template classes A and B

```
template <typename T> class A { /* ... */ };
template <typename T> class B { /* ... */ };
```

Now I would like to write a function that performs different actions, depending on which base classes are implemented in the passed argument.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& object) {
  if ( /* T inherits from some A<S1> */ )
    std::cout << "object has type A";
  if ( /* T inherits from some B<S2> */ )
    std::cout << "object has type B";
}
```

I guess I could add `S1` and `S2` as template parameters to foo but specifying them manually for each call is a great hassle. In theory, if `T` is known, the compiler should be able to check whether it inherits any `A<S>`.

Can this be done?

edit:

In addition to the solution of StoryTeller, I am using this piece of code to cast my `T`-objects accordingly:

```
template<template<typename...> class TT, class T>
struct specialization_base_of {

    template<typename... Args>
    static constexpr TT<Args...>  checkVal(TT<Args...> const&);

    static constexpr void checkVal(...);

    template<typename... Args>
    static constexpr TT<Args...>&  checkRef(TT<Args...> const&);

    static constexpr void checkRef(...);

    template<typename... Args>
    static constexpr TT<Args...> const& checkCref(TT<Args...> const&);

    static constexpr void checkCref(...);

    template<typename... Args>
    static constexpr TT<Args...>*  checkPtr(TT<Args...> const&);

    static constexpr void checkPtr(...);

    using value_type = decltype(checkVal(std::declval<T>()));
    using ref_type = decltype(checkRef(std::declval<T>()));
    using cref_type = decltype(checkCref(std::declval<T>()));
    using ptr_type = decltype(checkPtr(std::declval<T>()));
};
```

Comment: you can't check if T inherits from any A<> or B<>.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of)?

Comment: Alternative: make all A<> and B<> inherit from a class C and check inheritance from C

Comment: also, some compilers use `__is_base_of(Base, Drived)` to check inheritance

Comment: Why can't it be `template <typename T> void foo(const A<T>& obj)` directly?

Comment: @JesperJuhl That would only work if the template argument of A or B is known.

Comment: @רועיאבידן Giving them all the same base class would only get me so far, as then the type parameter is still hidden. There is also no guarantee that no other classes inherit C as well.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Then the "object has type B" part would be missing. I do not want to split the function into multiple functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good old trick that relies on overload resolution should work here as well:

```
template<template<typename...> class TT, class T>
struct is_specialization_base_of {
    template<typename... Args>
    static constexpr std::true_type  check(TT<Args...> const&);

    static constexpr std::false_type check(...);

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};
```

The first template parameter is template name, which can accept any number of type argument. You need one, but why limit ourselves?

We then define two overloads, one is a template that accepts any hypothetical specialization of `TT`, and the second is a fallback that is a C-style variable argument function. This is the entire machinery right there. If we call `check` with any class that publicly derives from a hypothetical specialization of `TT`, the first overload is picked due to how overload resolution works. Otherwise the fallback is chosen.

The value of our trait is determined by the type produced in the unevaluated context of `decltype`, there the overload resolution is performed, but since it's an unevaluated context nothing needs to be defined, only declared. `decltype` therefore yields the result type.

[Here's a simple test suite](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7a2df2bebe379ba):

```
struct C1 : A<int> {};
struct C2 : B<int> {};

struct C3 : A<int>, B<char> {};

static_assert(is_specialization_base_of<A, C1>::value);
static_assert(!is_specialization_base_of<B, C1>::value);

static_assert(!is_specialization_base_of<A, C2>::value);
static_assert(is_specialization_base_of<B, C2>::value);

static_assert(is_specialization_base_of<A, C3>::value);
static_assert(is_specialization_base_of<B, C3>::value);
```

I'll leave the exercise of plugging this trait into your template function to you. I'd just recommend turning those `if`'s into `if constexpr` for some added goodies.

Comment: This trick fails for, for example, `struct C4 : A<int>, A<char> {};`

Comment: @xskxzr - Yeah, ambiguity will kill it. But then again `std::is_base_of` is so useful because it's allowed to cheat. IIRC similar traits in C++03 had the same problem with MI.